# rails jquery disable the download button until the form is saved

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**view**

I have created a form which has save and download button. I want the save button to be disabled until completion of all fields and download button to be disabled until the form is being saved.

```html
- content_for :javascript_includes do
  = javascript_include_tag "dropdown.js", "business.js", "bootstrap-toggle.min.js"
.col-sm-12
  .main-login.main-center.customer_details
= nested_form_for(@customer_detail) do |f|
  - all_views_side_error_messages!(@customer_detail)
  .form-alignment
    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :customer_name,"Organisation/Customer Name", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :customer_name, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :residential_type,"Residential Type", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.check_box :residential_type, autofocus: true, "data-width" => "200", class: "toggle-two-resident select-resident col-sm-3"
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :customer_id,"Customer ID", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :customer_id, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :attention_to,"Attention To", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :attention_to, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :address,"Address", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_area :address, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :city,"City", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :city, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :pin_code,"Pin Code", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :pin_code, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        %div{id: 'state_field'}
          = f.label :state,"State", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.select(:state, options_for_select(State.collect_state),{},{class: "selectpicker col-sm-3 column-width-change", prompt: "Select State", "data-live-search": "true"})
        %div.hide{id: 'country_field'}
          = f.label :country,"Country", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.select(:country, CountryList.collect_country_list,{}, {class: "selectpicker add_class_country dropdown_country col-sm-3 column-width-change", title: "select country", "data-live-search": "true"})

    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :email,"Email", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :contact_no,"Contact No", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :contact_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :website,"Website", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :website, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        %div.hide{id: 'currency_field'}
          = f.label :currency_type,"Currency Type", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.select(:currency_type, CurrencyType.collect_currency_type,{},{class: "selectpicker dropdown_business column-width-change", prompt: 'Select', "data-live-search": "true"})
        %div{id: 'change_resident'}
          = f.label :business_type,"Business Type", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.select(:business_type, BusinessType.collect_business_type,{},{class: "selectpicker dropdown_business column-width-change", prompt: 'Select', "data-live-search": "true"})
          %br
          %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :service_tax_reg_no,"Service tax Registration No", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :service_tax_reg_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :pan_no,"PAN No", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :pan_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
        = f.label :local_sales_tax_reg_no,"Local Sales Tax Registration No", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :local_sales_tax_reg_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
        = f.label :central_sales_tax_no,"Central Sales Tax Registration No", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
        = f.text_field :central_sales_tax_no, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
    %br

    = render partial: 'customer_details/goods_address', locals: {customer_detail: @customer_detail}
    %br

    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-12
          = f.label :opening_bal,"Opening Balance if any?", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
          = f.text_field :opening_bal, autofocus: true, class: "col-sm-3"
          = f.label :business_center,"From which business center invoice is being raised?", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right business_center-alignment"
          = f.select(:business_center, BusinessType.collect_business_type,{},{class: "selectpicker dropdown_business column-width-change", prompt: 'Select', "data-live-search": "true"})
    %br


    .fieldset
      .row
        .col-sm-3
          = f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary"
        .col-sm-3
          = f.submit "cancel", type: :reset, class: "btn btn-primary"
        .col-sm-3
          - if @customer_detail.save
            = link_to "Download", download_csv_customer_detail_path(@customer_detail.id, format: "csv"), class: "btn btn-primary.disabled"
        .col-sm-3
          = link_to("Print", "javascript:print()", class: "btn btn-primary")
```

I dont know how to write conditions for it in the JS.can someone please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to Ruby on Rails?

Comment: I have created this form in ruby on rails

Comment: Apparently you did but your question is not related to rails. You need javascript/jquery to do what you want here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `disabled: true` option to the `Save` button and remove it when the form is submitted/saved using Javascript/jQuery. Submitting the form via AJAX will come in handy here. Read [this](http://stefan.magnuson.co/articles/rails/simpler-handling-of-ajax-form-errors-in-rails-4/) article to learn how to handle form submission via AJAX in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: $("#download_form").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   if $('.save-form').on('click', function(){
   $("#download_form").removeAttr('disabled');
 });                      by using this JS code I can't able to enable the download button again after saving the form.can u help me more?

Comment: Please go through the article I linked in my post.  Even if you manage to solve the current problem, you'll face a lot more in future. Friendly advice: you need to spend some more time learning Javascript. It is an essential part of web development.